# How do I solve this std::bad_cast with from antlrcpp::Any?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, antlr4

I'm trying to parse an expression with ANTLR4. Therefor I'm using the visitor pattern and creating an abstract syntax tree.

The result can be an expression or something other (which I removed from this example code). The visitor expects a return type of `antlrcpp::Any` so the elements of the abstract syntax tree are converted to`antlrcpp::Any`.

But I'm getting  a `std::bad_cast` if I'm trying to convert the result back from `antlrcpp::Any` to `std::shared_ptr<Expression>`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

#include "antlr4-runtime.h"
#include "Parser/SimpleLangLexer.h"
#include "Parser/SimpleLangParser.h"
#include "Parser/SimpleLangBaseVisitor.h"

struct Expression;

struct Node {
    virtual ~Node() { }
};

struct Expression: public Node {
    int constValue;
    Expression(int constValue) : constValue(constValue) { }
    virtual ~Expression() override { }
};

struct AstVisitor: public SimpleLangBaseVisitor {

    virtual antlrcpp::Any visitTopLevelElement(SimpleLangParser::TopLevelElementContext *ctx) override {
        std::shared_ptr<Expression> expression = ctx->expression()->accept(this);
        return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Node>(expression);
    }

    virtual antlrcpp::Any visitIntExpr(SimpleLangParser::IntExprContext *ctx) override {

        std::string strInteger = ctx->INTEGER()->getSymbol()->getText();
        int constValue = std::stoi(strInteger);

        auto intExpr = std::make_shared<Expression>(constValue);
        return intExpr;
    }
};

int main() {

    std::string line = "123;";
    antlr4::ANTLRInputStream input(line);
    SimpleLangLexer lexer(&input);
    antlr4::CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);
    SimpleLangParser parser(&tokens);

    antlr4::tree::ParseTree *tree = parser.start();
    // Prints:
    // > (start (topLevelElement (expression 123) ;) <EOF>)
    std::cout << std::endl << tree->toStringTree(&parser) << std::endl;

    AstVisitor astVisitor;
    antlrcpp::Any result = tree->accept(&astVisitor);

    // Prints:
    // > Dn
    // std::cout << result.get_typeinfo().name() << std::endl;

    // Error:
    // > terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
    //     what():  std::bad_cast
    std::shared_ptr<Node> node = result;
    std::shared_ptr<Expression> iexpr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Expression>(node);

    // Expected:
    // > 123
    std::cout << iexpr->constValue << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Implementation of antlrcpp::Any](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Cpp/runtime/src/support/Any.h)

My grammar:

```
grammar SimpleLang;

start
    : topLevelElement* EOF
    ;

topLevelElement
    : expression ';'
    ;

expression
    : IDENTIFIER #identifierExpr
    | INTEGER #intExpr
    ;

IDENTIFIER
    : [_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*
    ;

INTEGER
    : [0-9]+
    ;

WS: [ \r\n\t] -> skip;
```

Note: I greatly reduced my code for this question and I hope it makes still sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
antlrcpp::Any result = tree->accept(&astVisitor);
// Error:
// > terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
//     what():  std::bad_cast

std::shared_ptr<Node> node = tree->accept(result);
```

here you call `tree->accept` first with a pointer to an `astVisitor`.

Then you take the result of that, and pass it to `tree->accept`, which probably expects a pointer to `SimpleLangBaseVisitor`.  But the first `tree->accept` call returned an `Any` that probably doesn't contain a pointer to a `SimpleLangBaseVisitor`.

So it throws an error.

---

As an aside, that `Any` you are using is missing `std::typeinfo const& get_typeinfo() const`.  If you had that, you could do some `get_typeinfo().name()` printf debugging to get a clue what is going wrong.

If you have access to the source code add:

```
struct Base {
  virtual ~Base();
  virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
  std::typeinfo const& get_typeinfo() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base {
  // ...
  std::typeinfo const& get_typeinfo() const override {
    return typeid(T);
  }
};
```

and to `Any` itself:

```
std::typeinfo const& get_typeinfo() const {
  if (!_ptr) return typeid(std::nullptr_t);
  return ptr->get_typeinfo();
}
```

once you have that, `std::cerr << some_any.get_typeinfo().name() << std::endl;` will solve many "why am I getting a bad_cast?!" pains.  But it does require that both your code, and the code generating the Any, be built with this modified `Any`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I edited my question. `std::bad_cast` is thrown in the line `std::shared_ptr<Node> node = result;`. I rebuild my local copy on Any. But I cannot find what the type name `Dn` means.

Comment: @JP3141 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e6451847ce85e93 (nullptr).

Comment: Thanks! `result.isNull()` yields also `true`.